# How do I implement the Backbone model in latest Parse js sdk (1.6.2)?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform, backbone.js-collections

The Parse Collection class corresponding to Backbone.Collection is no more in the SDK. It used to be there in 1.2.13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of September 9th, 2015, the Parse Javascript SDK no longer contains backbone specific behavior. You can reference a previous version of the JS SDK (http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.5.0.min.js) to access the backbone specific behaviors but understand that branch is no longer maintained.

> V1.6.0 — SEPTEMBER 9, 2015
>
> New Features
>
> Designed to work with ES6. Parse.Object can be treated as a class, and
>   can be subclassed with the extend keyword
>
> When subclassing Parse.Object, you will need to call
>   Parse.Object.registerSubclass()
>
> Better support for different platforms, with custom builds for React
>   Native and Node
>
> All platforms still use the “parse” npm module, but node.js
>   applications should use “require(‘parse/node’)” and React Native
>   applications should use “require(‘parse/react-native’)”
>
> Objects can be created from JSON with Parse.Object.fromJSON()
>
> Pointers can be generated with Parse.Object.prototype.toPointer()
>
> All SDK configuration is now stored in Parse.CoreManager
>
> Controllers for concepts like local storage can be hot-swapped via
>   CoreManager
>
> Changes
>
> **SDK no longer contains Backbone-specific behavior. Moving forward, the
>   core SDK will not be tied to any single framework, but we will work
>   with the community to produce up-to-date bindings like Parse+React.
>   The major changes are the removal of Parse.Collection, and allowing
>   Parse.Objects to act as event channels.**
>
> SDK no longer ships with Underscore.js included.
>
> Field type mismatches (trying to increment a string field) will now
>   throw exceptions on the client side.
>
> In server environments where the current user has not been explicitly
>   enabled, fetching the current user will now return null instead of
>   throwing. Attempts to change the current user through logIn or become
>   will still throw.
>
> Parse.Ops no longer publicly expose their values

Quoted from: https://parse.com/docs/downloads

Comment: I recommend reconsidering your dependence on the Parse framework.

If you decide you want to move forward with Parse + BackBone, the best solution is to use Parse's REST API directly with backbone. See this project: https://github.com/neebz/backbone-parse

Comment: Your point is well taken. I am willing to go to Firebase to keep Backbone support. I'll try this approach (neebz's code ) too.