# Parse.com JavaScript SDK 1.6 integration with Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, parse-platform

guys!

I have a Parse.com APP in Production and I need to migrate it because Parse is shutting down. I used Parse Javascript SDK v.1.3.2 to build it. And at this version we had Backbone inside the Parse.com SDK.

However, to be able to point my APP to a new server, I would need to use the latest Parse JavaScript SDK v.1.6. That's the point were the problem begins. This SDK version no longer contains Backbone.

My APP uses Backbone Collections and Events exhaustively and I could not find a way to integrate Parse JavaScript SDK v.1.6 with Backbone to use their Collections and Events.

Does anybody have a solution for that?

Cheers!!

Oscar

Comment: `parse.com`... didn't they stop their services?

Comment: FYI     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32722575/how-do-i-implement-the-backbone-model-in-latest-parse-js-sdk-1-6-2